# How to fold subroutines in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, code-structure

How to fold subroutines in VScode? I am reading Fortran code in VScode, which contain the main program and many subroutines. The VScode can also fold codes but seem randomly. How to make VScode recognize the entire subroutine and fold it？

perhaps change some setting or install some plugin？

Comment: What does this  mean: *"The VScode can also fold codes but seem randomly."*? How randomly? Please show your problem and tell us which Extensions do you use in VS Code. See [tour], [ask] and [mre].

Comment: have you installed a language support extension like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fortran-lang.linter-gfortran yet?

Comment: I have indeed installed this Modern Fortran extension, otherwise there is no syntax highlighting.   I notice the VScode identifies the fold range based on code indentation and comments rather than code structure. Fortran code does not strictly require indent alignment, which, combined with the interspersed comments, makes VScode fold code randomly. In the Notepad++, every 'subroutine' will marked a square symbol allow you fold up the code from 'subroutine' to 'end subroutine' with a simple click, so you can see the **code structure** clearly. Why VScode have not embrace this feature yet?

Comment: if you want to ask an informed question, you should preread https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding